# Transformation. Geometry.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

This is the question which I've been solving for so long. And I couldn't solve it. Is there anyone can explain the solution for me?

[image]

Comment: Very few people will bother to read a question that you obviously couldn't be bothered to type, be bothered to include your work, nor be bothered to title usefully. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformation shown in the picture is rotation of square $ABCD$ through an angle of $45^\circ$ in clockwise direction & square $A'B'C'D'$ is the transformed position of square $ABCD$

Let $a$ be the length of equal legs of the blue right triangle then its hypotenuse is given as $$\sqrt{a^2+a^2}=a\sqrt 2$$

since, the areas of square $ABCD$ & square $A'B'C'D'$ are equal to $36\mathrm{cm^2}$ hence their each side is $\sqrt{36}=6\ \mathrm{cm}$. Now, one should have the edge length of square $ABCD$ $$AB=a+a\sqrt 2+a=6$$  $$a(2+\sqrt 2)=6\implies a=3(2-\sqrt 2)$$
Now, the area of (blue) shaded part $$=4\times (\text{area of shaded right triangle})$$ $$=4\times \frac{1}{2}(3(2-\sqrt 2))^2$$
$$=\color{red}{36(3-2\sqrt 2)\ \mathrm{cm^2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

In the picture it looks like the transformation is a clockwise rotation about 45 degrees. Since the area of the square is 36, its side length is 6. Note that the equilateral triangles in the corners of the square get mapped to the blue triangles by the transformation. Denote by $x$ the length of a leg of one of the blue triangles. Then by the previous observation $2x+\sqrt{2}x =6$, so the leg of one of the blue triangles has length $3 (2-\sqrt{2})$. Thus the area of the blue region is equal to $4 \cdot 0.5 \cdot (3(2-\sqrt{2}))^2=36 (3-2 \sqrt{2})$